# Can someone please explain to me, easily, how to use the prepare for segue function?

Tags: objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a Text field called textField1 in ViewController1 and I have another textFeild2 in viewController2. In view controller 3, I have 2 labels called: myLabel1, myLabel2. I want the data that I entered in the first two text fields to change the label. Please help me with this.

Comment: There are literally thousand of answers on SO about passing data between view controllers. You should do a search first before asking yet another one of these.

Answer (score 2):

In order to pull this off, you would need a way to pass `textField1.text` into viewController2, so that when you segue to viewController3, you have both the values available to you.

#### You can accomplish this by using the `-prepareForSegue:` method at two different times.

#### The first segue you will need is the Segue from viewController1 to viewController2.

This segue's only job is to pass the value of `textField1` to `viewController2`. Put this in the implementation file for `viewController1.m`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        // Make sure you are targeting the correct segue, since you can have
        // multiple segues spawned from a single view controller
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"NAME_OF_SEGUE_TO_VC2"])
        {
            // Get reference to the destination view controller so you
            // can assign the value of textField1 somewhere inside viewController2
            ViewController2 *vc2 = [segue destinationViewController];
            vc2.textField1Text = self.textField1.text;
            // Now viewController2 has the value of textField1.text
        }
    }
```

#### Now for the second segue (to viewController3):

Put this in your `viewController2.m` file:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        // Make sure you are targeting the correct segue, since you can have
        // multiple segues spawned from a single view controller
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"NAME_OF_SEGUE_TO_VC3"])
        {
            // Get reference to the destination view controller so you
            // can assign the value of textField1 & textField2 to viewController3
            ViewController3 *vc3 = [segue destinationViewController];
            vc3.mylabel1 = self.textField1Text;
            vc3.mylabel2 = self.textField2.text;

            // Now viewController3 has the values of both textField1 & textField2

        }
    }
```

And put this in your `viewController2.h` file:

```
// This will store the value of textField1 inside of viewController2
// and will be assigned before the segue from viewController1 to viewController2
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *textField1Text;
```

I haven't tested the code above, so it might not be perfect, but the concept is there, and should point you in the right direction. Please let me know if you have any questions.

**Hope this helps!**